# How to persist data in react native app with usememo hook

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

I'm writing an application in react native and I came across a problem - the application will have several screens (I use react-navigation and react-navigation-tabs) and two-color themes (light and dark) managed by context and hooks. What I would like to achieve is the selected theme to be remembered by the app (the light theme will be set as default, and after switching to dark, leaving the application and returning the dark theme should still be applied).

EDIT #2: One answer from yesterday (that disappeared for some reason) suggested the use of redux and local storage so I'm editing the paragraph below to clarify the situation.

Easiest way would be to use sync storage/localStorage (I already have working version of the app using local storage), but one tutorial I found on the web uses the user memo hook for this purpose, and while it should work, it isn't (in my case at least), and I don't know why...

My App.js file below:

```js
imports ...

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: Home,
  List: List,
});

const App = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);

export default () => (
  <ThemeProvider>
    <App />
  </ThemeProvider>
```

ThemeContext.js file:

```js
imports ...

export const ThemeContext = createContext();

export const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [colors, setColors] = useState(themes.lightTheme) //setting light theme as default

    const value = useMemo(
      () => ({
          colors,
          setColors,
      }),
      [colors, setColors],
    );

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

And Home.js file, with a button to switch between themes:

```js
imports ...

export const Home = () => {
  const { colors, setColors } = useContext(ThemeContext);

  const toggleTheme = () => {
    if (colors.type === 'light') {
      setColors(themes.darkTheme);
      } else {
      setColors(themes.lightTheme);
      }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <View style={{...styles.mainView, backgroundColor: colors.backgroundColor }}>
        <Text style={{...styles.mainText, color: colors.color}}>Hello Native World</Text>
        <Button title='toggle theme' onPress={toggleTheme} />
      </View>
    </>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainView: {
    paddingTop: 40,
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  mainText: {
    fontSize: 40,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The key file you have to change is your context file:

```
export const ThemeContext = createContext();

export const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [colors, setColors] = useState(themes.lightTheme) //setting light theme as default

    const value = useMemo(
      () => ({
          colors,
          setColors,
      }),
      [colors, setColors],
    );

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

I don't really understand why you use `useMemo`, but I will leave it. From a quick glance I'd say that it is not needed, but I don't know your app. What you want is something like this:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-community/async-storage'

export const ThemeContext = createContext()

export function usePersistedState(key, initialState) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(() => {})

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getAndSetInitialState() {
      const persistedState = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
      if (persistedState) {
        setState(JSON.parse(persistedState))
      } else if (typeof initialState === 'function') {
        return setState(initialState())
      } else {
        return setState(initialState)
      }
    }
    getAndSetInitialState()
  }, [key])

  function setPersistedState(value) {
    AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value))
    setState(value)
  }

  return [state, setPersistedState]
}

export const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [colors, setColors] = usePersistedState("your_storage_key", themes.lightTheme) //setting light theme as default

  const value = useMemo(
    () => ({
      colors,
      setColors,
    }),
    [colors, setColors]
  )

  return <ThemeContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</ThemeContext.Provider>
}
```

I might have missed some edge cases, but this way your app will load it's state from the storage and save it's state into the storage.

EDIT: I'm not sure how `useMemo` would help, AsyncStorage is the easiest solution imo.

Comment: Exactly as You said - AsyncStorage is the right (best? most common?) way to do this. I saw usage of useMemo instead of AsyncStorage in one tutorial, but it's apparently a dead end.

Comment: useMemo serves a different use-case and has nothing to do with persistence but rather - as the name suggests - with memoization. I can recommend the following article: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback/

Comment: useMemo is RAM memoized, useMemo with storage would be persistent memoization, which would be cool